# How to hide a output message for MD and MOVE command in batch script?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create folders and move files inside the newly created folder.

I have implemented the code and it's working fine.

```
@(
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
ECHO OFF
)

FOR %%a IN (
%1\*
) DO @(
@FOR /F "Tokens=2-3 delims=- " %%A IN ('
dir  /A-D /T:W "%%a"
^| Find /I "%%~nxa"
') DO @(
MD "%1\Y%%B\%%B%%A\"
MOVE /Y "%%a" "%%~dpaY%%B\%%B%%A\%%~nxa"
)
)
```

While executing this batch file **batchFileName directoryPath**, files moved properly as per requirement but I am getting status like below in cmd:

[image]

This will be odd while moving thousands of file at a time, I need to show a custom message instead of following default output.

How to hide subdirectory or file already exists and file moved messages in output command promt?

Comment: Append [`> nul`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to hide output messages, `2> nul` to hide error messages and `> nul 2>&1` to hide both...

Comment: great, this works fine.

Answer (score 2):

We can check if the sub directory already exists and if it does not bother to try to create it, or we can hide the error by redirecting `>` stderr `2` to `nul` to hide the error.

We can also hide all regular move file text using redirection `>` of stdout `1` to `nul` to hide that info

Note, because you used the construct I described in the second example, we no longer need to use "Dir" as the outer `For` loop will give us the file path, name, and date in separate parameters.  So we only need to parse the output from that variable as a text string which will be faster than using dir piped to find.

I am walking to train so I'll just edit this version for now

```
@(
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  ECHO OFF
)

FOR %%a IN (
  "%~1\*"
) DO @(
  @FOR /F "Tokens=2-3 delims=- " %%A IN ('
    dir  /A-D /T:W "%%~a"
    ^| Find /I "%%~nxa"
  ') DO @(
    IF NOT EXIST "%%~dpa\Y%%B\%%B%%A\" (
      MD "%%~dpa\Y%%B\%%B%%A\"
    )
     MOVE /Y "%%~fa" "%%~dpaY%%B\%%B%%A\%%~nxa" >nul
   )
)
```